# Android Kotlin synchronized and FileInputStream.read causes thread starvation warning

Tags: android, kotlin, file, synchronization

I would like to prevent reads and writes from occuring at the same time by using 'synchronized'.  However, that causes a warning: ***Possibly blocking call in non-blocking context could lead to thread starvation***

```
fun read(inputStream: FileInputStream) {
    synchronized(this) {
        // warning: Possibly blocking call in non-blocking context could lead to thread starvation
        var nextByte: Int = inputStream.read()    
    }
}

fun write(outputStream: FileOutputStream, data: ByteArray) {
    synchronized(this) {
        outputStream.write(data)
    }
}
```

I can't rewrite this code at the moment to coroutines.  Is there another way to deal with this?

EDIT: Wanted to add if this is helpful to anyone, using locks instead of synchronize was useful to my use case.  Not sure about anyone elses.

Comment: What’s preventing you from rewriting to use coroutines (or some other framework for running asynchronous code)? To do this properly on Android, the easiest solutions are to use coroutines or RxJava.

Comment: @Tenfour04 This is just a small part of a legacy system that does not support coroutines.  Should I change it to support coroutines, that would propagate up and I would have to change quite a bit of the framework to also support coroutines, and that is out of scope.  Same with RxJava.

Comment: So this code is called on the main thread by the higher up code, or are you getting a false warning? If it’s called on the main thread and you can’t change that, there is no solution that can resolve the issue.

Comment: So because I couldn't do much about this code in terms of changing to coroutines, I switched to locks instead of synchronized and it seems to solve this problem.  If someone else has a similar problem, maybe this will be an avenue of investigation for them as well.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else, I changed from synchronize() to reentrantlock.  Theres a few ways of using reentrantlock, but there is a function that closely resembles the block structure of synchronize().

```
lock.withLock {
  // your code here
}
```

Instead of

```
synchronized(object) {
  // your code here
}
```